# Can't install Mongodb on Mac OS 10.9

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I had OS 10.8 on my MacBook Air, then I upgraded to OS 10.9, everything is good except mongodb does not work.

I installed Xcode 5 then I reinstalled the brew on my Mac but mongodb does not work.

It is installed at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.8
```

But when I execute `mongod`, I get this result: `mongod: command not found`

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: What's your `$PATH` look like?

Comment: Do you see it running with "ps aux"? Try "mongo" to access the console.

Comment: How can i show the $PATH ?

Comment: Do you use this command? brew install mongodb

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling it with brew but be sure to update it first

```
brew services stop mongodb
brew uninstall mongodb

brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
brew services start mongodb-community
```